# Non negativity condition for polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, sums-of-squares

Let $p(x)=3ax^2+2bx+(1-a-b), \,\,\,\,0<x<1$

What are the conditions on a and b to $p(x)>0$

Could someone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: complete the square. This means writing $p(x)$ in the form
$$p(x)=A(x+B)^2+C
$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$ are constants possibly depending on $a$ and $b$, but not on $x$. When you're done you will have expressed $p(x)$ as a nonnegative piece $A(x+B)^2$ (this requires $A\ge0$) and a constant $C$. So if we require $p(x)>0$ for all $x$ we must have $A\ge0$ and $C>0$.

In your case you'd complete the square by starting out
$$
P(x)=3a(x^2+\frac{2b}{3a}x)+(1-a-b) .
$$
To get this first section in the form $A(x+B)^2$ you'd want to complete the square with $(\frac b{3a})^2$. To repair what you've just done, you need to subtract it off again:
$$P(x)=3a\left(x^2+\frac{2b}{3a}x + (\frac b{3a})^2 - (\frac b{3a})^2)\right) + (1-a-b).$$
Next, regroup:
$$\begin{align}
P(x)&=3a\left(x^2+\frac{2b}{3a}x + (\frac b{3a})^2\right) -3a(\frac b{3a})^2 + (1-a-b).\\
&=3a\left(x+\frac b{3a}\right)^2 -3a(\frac b{3a})^2 + (1-a-b).\\
\end{align}
$$
From this last expression you can read off $A$, $B$, $C$. (You can simplify $C$ down to a more tidy expression.)

Comment: sorry,  I not understand because according to the above $a>0 $ but if $a=-1.6$ and $b=2.5$, $p(x)>0$

Comment: I see, you require $p(x)>0$ only for $0<x<1$. The above argument finds conditions on $a,b$ if we require $p(x)>0$ for all $x$. For your problem you need to argue more carefully. Since $p$ is a quadratic, there are four cases: (a) it is increasing throughout $(0,1)$, (b) it is decreasing throughout $(0,1)$, (c) it achieves its minimum value within $(0,1)$, (d) it achieves its maximum value within $(0,1)$. You will need to argue each of these four cases separately.  For example, in case (a) the only requirement is $p(0)>0$.

Comment: and the other  cases?

Comment: ...(continued) but in case (a) you also need to express the condition "p is increasing throughout (0,1)" as a statement about the derivative of $p(x)$ when $x$ in $(0,1)$. The argument for case (b) is similar. My solution handles case (c) only, provided we impose the additional requirement $0<-\frac b{3a}<1$. For case (d) the requirements are $p(0)>0$ and $p(1)>0$ and $p''(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. You must have $3a>0$
2. The derivative is $6ax+2b$ vanishes at $x = -{{b}\over{3a}}$ which is the minimum if $a>0$.
3. Find $a,b$ such that $p(-{b\over{3a}})>0$.

Comment: sorry, I not understand because according to the above a>0a>0 but if a=−1.6a=−1.6 and b=2.5b=2.5, p(x)>0p(x)>0